# With knexjs, how do I compare two columns in the .where() function?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Using knexjs only (no bookshelf) I would like to do something like the following query:

```
select * from table1 where column1 < column2
```

However, when I do this:

```
.table("table1").select().where("column1", "<", "column2")
```

The SQL that knexjs generates is:

```
select * from table1 where column1 < 'column2'
```

Which doesn't give the desired result b/c it's not comparing the value from the column, it's comparing the value of the string, 'column2'.

Anyone know how to do what I'm wanting? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, so after some digging, it looks like it can be done *this* way. Not sure if this is best practice, but at the moment, it works so until I hear otherwise...

```
.table("table1").select().where("column1", "<", knex.raw("table1.column2"))
```

Again, not ideal, but it gets the job done. Just be sure to

```
import knex from "knex";
```

at the top of whatever file you're using this in.

Comment: .whereRaw("?? = ??", ["column1", "column2"]) works too

Comment: @GregHornby it works. Could you please explain why it works only with double question marks?

Comment: `??` represents a binding for an identifier like a column or table name. `?` represents a binding for a value, like a number, or string.

Answer (score 13):

As of knex 0.15.0 (July 2018), we now have:

```
table("table1").select().where("column1", "<", knex.ref("column2"))
```

See https://knexjs.org/#Ref

As Greg Hornby mentions in the comment to the other answer, you can also use `??` in a raw query to bind to a column or table name.