# Comparing two columns: <= does not work, but >= does

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I want to select `column1` data where it's less than or equal with `column2`. However, when I try using `<=` I get an empty result, despite having data in `column1` which is less than `column2`.

My code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    db('items').select().where('column1', '<=', 'column2').then((notify)=>{
      console.log(notify)
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express', notify:notify })
  })
})
```

and the result:

```
[]
```

which as you see is empty!

If I use greater or equal:

```
 .where('column1', '>=', 'column2')
```

I get all the rows:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    column_id: 1,
    column1: 99,
    column2: 10, },
  RowDataPacket {
    column_id: 2,
    column1: 10,
    column2: 10, },
  RowDataPacket {
    column_id: 3,
    column1: 29,
    column2: 12,} ]
```

Why is this?

Comment: Can u check/log what query returned from knex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, SQL works this way, but Knex doesn't! Knex is essentially comparing the value of `column1` to the *string* 'column2'. So, it would be as if we ran the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM items
    WHERE column1 <= 'column2';
```

Now, in MySQL (MariaDB in my examples) a `<=` comparison for an integer against a string returns `0` (false). However, a `>=` comparison returns `1`, which explains the confusing results you're seeing. Some other databases would display an error (Postgres for example):

```
postgres=# SELECT 1 <= 'foo';
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "foo"
LINE 1: SELECT 1 <= 'foo';                   ^
```

but MariaDB will let you get away with it:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT 1 <= 'foo';
+------------+
| 1 <= 'foo' |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT 1 >= 'foo';
+------------+
| 1 >= 'foo' |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

To solve this, you need to tell Knex that you actually want the column value on the right hand side of the comparison, not a string. You can accomplish this using [`knex.ref`](http://knexjs.org/#Ref). Try this:

```
db("items")
  .where("column1", "<=", db.ref("column2"))
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

See also: [With knexjs, how do I compare two columns in the .where() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447326/with-knexjs-how-do-i-compare-two-columns-in-the-where-function).